# Bootstrap Carousel , only works in a jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have almost finished my bootstrap carousel for my homepage. There is just one little problem i don't understand. It only works inside an div with jumbotron as class. Why is that?

If i don't have a jumbotron around it, it wont show anything..

**Some code:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class=".col-md-6">

        <!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
        <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                    <div class="fill" style="background-image: url('/images/hotel1.jpg');"></div>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
                    <div class="fill" style="background-image: url('/images/hotel2.jpg');"></div>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
                    <div class="fill" style="background-image: url('/images/hotel3.jpg');"></div>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="icon-prev"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="icon-next"></span>
            </a>

        </header>

    </div>


</div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
<script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000 //changes the speed
    })
</script>
```

**CSS code:**

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel,
.item,
.active {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}



.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

footer {
    margin: 50px 0;
}
```

Hope someone can see and guide me in the right direction, because this is the first carousel i have made.

Answer (score 0):

you problem results from multiple little issues:

### [here is my bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/0EW4wEbReM#)

I didn't change much, you forgot data-ride in your header:

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

And the div before your carousel has a wrong class:

```
<div class=".col-md-6"><!--it shouldn't have the dot there-->
<div class="col-md-6"><!--we both know how frustating these little dots can be-->
```

Comment: It still does only work with the jumbotron class... not the col-md-6 class or any other :(